# How to limit accepted SSL/TLS versions when using Sim800

Tags: ssl, command, at-command, sim800

I'm using sim800 module to connect to a server using TLS. Due to a security policy in our company, the module must not continue the connection establishment if the remote host tries to use and older version of SSL/TLS.
Is there a command or setting in sim800 that can be used to choose the TLS/SSL version when connecting to a server?

*I have searched its SSL and AT command manuals and couldn't find anything useful.

Answer (score 1):

There's a TLS firmware of sim800 and you can upgrade to it, this firmware use TLS version 1.2 but you can't select the version of TLS,infact sim800 use latest version of TLS that firmware supported.
TLS Firmware version
1418B09SIM800C24_TLS